# Is there a way to make aliases as short as possible?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

For instance, if you have three tokens, let's say [city], [state], and [country]
is there a way to do this:

/[city]-[state]-[country]

and then let's say there are three cities, Venice, in different places
the first, Venice, Florida, United States would get this url

/venice

the second, Venice, California, United States would get this url

/venice-california

the third, Venice, Italy would get this url:

/venice-italy

Notice that it does not cut an individual token, only cuts off the extra tokens as they are not needed (in the case of Italy, there is no state so pauthauto automatically skips this token).
From reading the documention, it looks like Pathauto's default behavior is to do this:

/venice

/venice-1

/venice-2

and so on... when what I want to do is make the first one the "venice" and any additinal ones get additial tokens as needed, so if Venice, Italy is first then they will get /venice

If there's a way to do this with pathauto, how would you do it?
If not, what's the best way to make a module that does this?
Can a module modify how pauthauto works without modifying pathauto itself?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hook_pathauto_alias_alter()` is nearest to your query.

First parameter `$alias` will be newly created alias by the Pathauto module. You would have to analyze it with some regex pattern for undesired pattern generation.

The second parameter will give you contextual picture of item in associated array.

`module` definitely be `taxonomy_term`
`source` system path of taxonomy e.g. `taxonomy/term/<tid>`

I think you will have pretty much to analyze the term and get its hierarchical info to update `$alias` variable.

Answer (score 0):

What about [`path_save()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/path_save/7) called X number of times with whatever tokens you want in the URL fragment?

What you're asking isn't really a Pathauto question I think, as the uniqueness you describe is pretty subjective.

You could keep a one-to-many database table of node IDs for the allowed aliases you want per city.